# Chrome native tooltip does not move when changing element if title attributes are the same

Tags: google-chrome, tooltip

On moving mouse from one element to another element, the tooltip position does not change if the title attribute of the two elements is the same.

Chrome issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142002

Chrome version tested: 44.0.2403.130

### Try live here or jsFiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/r32kfk1n/

```css
body
{
        padding: 50px;
}

div
{
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #eeeeff;
}

div:hover
{
        background-color: #ddddff;
}
```

```html
<div title="Title Attribute Value">Hover &rarr; HERE &larr;</div>
<div title="Title Attribute Value">Then move the mouse to here</div>
<br><br><br>
<div title="Title Attribute Value">Hover &rarr; HERE &larr;</div>
<div title="Something Different" class="second">Then move the mouse to here</div>
```

Looking for possible workarounds to this.

Comment: I've just encountered this issue myself. Did you ever find a work around?

Comment: @LaurenceC no I haven't

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I didn't find an answer so removed the title attribute in the end. Sad times.